# Flowbite modal backdrop not hide when close with function

Tags: javascript, flowbite

When i close Modal by function the backdrop dont hide until I press on ESC key

```
  <div class="block space-y-4 md:flex md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4">
        <!-- Modal toggle -->
        <button data-modal-target="small-modal" data-modal-toggle="small-modal"
            class="block w-full md:w-auto text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center"
            type="button">
            Small modal
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Small Modal -->
    <div id="small-modal" tabindex="-1"
        class="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden w-full p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
        <div class="relative w-full max-w-md max-h-full">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
                <!-- Modal header -->
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-5 border-b rounded-t">
                    <h3 class="text-xl font-medium text-gray-900">
                        Small modal
                    </h3>
                    <button type="button"
                        class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ml-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center"
                        data-modal-hide="small-modal">
                        <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6" />
                        </svg>
                        <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="p-6 space-y-6">
                    <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                        lorem ipsum
                    </p>
                    <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                        Lorem ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 border-t border-gray-200 rounded-b">
                    <button data-modal-hide="small-modal" type="button"
                        class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-200 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10">Decline</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const smallmodal = new Modal(document.getElementById('small-modal'));

        function closemodal() {
            smallmodal.hide();
        }
    </script>
```

basically i try to close modal by function only, this modal will contain form, after testing the field and if everything is all right i will run async function to write in database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. Flowbite modal have `_destroyBackdropEl()` function and `_backdropEl` variable but none of them works for me.  Then I decided to manually remove the backdrop after hiding the modal.
Here's the workaround that worked for me.

```js
const smallModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('small-modal'))

function closeModal() {
    smallModal.hide()
    document.querySelector("body > div[modal-backdrop]")?.remove()
}
```